# How to split a string after third space?

Tags: java, string, split

I am trying to split a string after every third space in Java. I have tried many regexs and no luck:

If I have a string:

```
Tuesday, August 11, 1993 Monday, September 10, 2015 Tuesday, January 21, 2015 Wednesday, July 15, 2015
```

I want this to split after the year (assuming its always 4 digits)

Best way to do this?? Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Why don't you split after "four digits" (instead of "the third space")?

Comment: I am unsure of how to do that. what would the regex be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split after each 4 digit match using a regular expression:

```
String toSplit = "Tuesday, August 11, 1993 Monday, September 10, 2015 Tuesday, January 21, 2015 Wednesday, July 15, 2015"; 
String[] split = toSplit.split("(?<=\\d{4})\\s");
```

If you want to be more rigorous and only split after an exactly formatted date, you could use this instead:

```
String[] split = toSplit.split("(?<=\\w{1,9}, \\w{1,9} \\d{1,2}, \\d{4})\\s");
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest to understand way would be to find a space three times, and then take two substrings - before and after the position of the space.

Use [`indexOf` overload that takes the `fromIndex` position](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)) in a loop, count three spaces, and then use `substring` twice.

```
String s = "quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
int pos = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; pos != -1 && i != 3 ; i++, pos++) {
    pos = s.indexOf(' ', pos);
}
System.out.println("'"+s.substring(0, pos-1)+"'");
System.out.println("'"+s.substring(pos, s.length())+"'");
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/gtCNQp)